# Как передать движение под мобильные устройства?

Tags: c#, unity3d, vector

Есть такой фрагмент кода,

```
public static float speed = 10;

void Update()
{
    Vector3 moveDir = Vector3.zero;
    moveDir.z = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

нужно переделать его для мобильных устройств, но не знаю как. Экран делится на две кнопки по нажатию на одну из которых объект двигался налево или направо. Пробовал менять переменную bool на тру или фолс, потом в update делать проверку.

Comment: Почитайте - https://habr.com/ru/post/437898/

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к кнопке компонент `EventTrigger`. `(Add Component > Event > EventTrigger)`

[image]

А вот и собственно скрипт движения: (Название: Drive

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Drive: MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Variables
    private bool CanGo = false;
    public static float speed = 10;
    #endregion

    #region Initialize
    private void Update()
    {
        if (CanGo)
        {
            Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
            Debug.Log(moveDir);
            gameObject.transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Functions
    public void Gas()
    {
        CanGo = true;
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        CanGo = false;
    }
    #endregion
}
```